# why remove attribute API not working for "is" attribute alone?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, web-component, custom-element

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var html = "<div id='issue' is='if'> some content </div>";
div.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(div);
var newDiv = document.querySelector("#issue");
newDiv.removeAttribute("id");
console.log(newDiv.outerHTML);
newDiv.removeAttribute("is");
console.log(newDiv.getAttribute("is"))
console.log(newDiv.outerHTML);
```

"is" attribute is removed in dom but it is not removed on doing outerHTML or innerHTML. I know "is" is a special attribute property for web components but it doesn't make sense even after removing attribute , it is not getting removed in outerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

From the HTML Living Standard:

[4.13.3 Core concepts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts)

> After a custom element is created, changing the value of the is attribute does not change the element's behavior, as it is saved on the element as its *is* value.

So "removeAttribute()" removes the *is* attribute, but not the *is* value.

Then outerHTML follows the serialization rules:

[13.3 Serializing HTML fragments](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#serialising-html-fragments)

> Because of the special role of the *is* attribute in signaling the creation of customized built-in elements, in that it provides a mechanism for parsed HTML to set the element's *is* value, we special-case its handling during serialization. This ensures that an element's *is* value is preserved through serialize-parse roundtrips.

> To ensure that serialize-parse roundtrips still work, the serialization process explicitly writes out the element's *is* value as an *is* attribute:

So the outerHTML serialization writes out the *is* attribute from the *is* value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any way for us to get element's "is" value?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSIKKANDARAFZALM - I can't see a direct way. But obviously you can use outerHTML to obtain it. e.g. `console.log(Object.assign(document.createElement('template'), {
  innerHTML: newDiv.cloneNode().outerHTML
}).content.firstChild.getAttribute("is"));`